# Handling Twitter access within app

Tags: ios, twitter, swift

I have been trying to add a 'Follow us on Twitter' button to my app, however I have ran into a few issues.

First of all, if the user does not have Twitter installed, the code that I intended to redirect them to the website version of Twitter instead, doesn't seem to work.

Also, how can I handle situations when the users is offline? I would like to display a UIAlert to warn them that they must have a connection to use Twitter.

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func followOnTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("twitter://user?screen_name=AffordIt_App")) {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString("https://twitter.com/AffordIt_App")) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need to see if the user has Twitter installed first.

```
@IBAction func followOnTwitter(sender: AnyObject) {
let screenName =  "Your Twitter Handle"
let appURL = NSURL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=\(screenName)")!
let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(screenName)")!

let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
  application.openURL(appURL)
} else {
  application.openURL(webURL)
}
}
```

I am new to this site and apologize if I am not posting in the proper format.